# Unity, EXE Crash Report Analysing. No crash in Unity

Tags: crash, unity-game-engine, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I work on a Unity project since a few months. I have no error on console and the game launches in unity without any problem.

When i build the game, and then click on the exe, the Game crash at start.
I have a crash log with crash and output.log files. I need help to analyse the log files. I would like to understand why my game crash at start.
I dont understand why the exe crash while in Unity it does not.

Link for the Log files :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzhtlmj204qh04l/2017-01-26_202252.rar?dl=0

error.txt :
http://pastebin.com/2TzEMyVV

output_log.txt
http://pastebin.com/cviF7mWZ

Comment: Could you either include the relevant sections of the crash log in your post? If the link goes dead, your post becomes useless to others. And if it's too large to include all, please make it available on some text-only service, so we don't have to download a random rar file from some dropbox.

Comment: i did for the 2 files txt. The dump crash file is on the Dropbox link.

Comment: It seems you're using 5.5.0f3. Did you try any other versions? Given where the crash occurs, I'm wondering if we're dealing with a Unity bug

Comment: Does the situation described here sound like something you might have done? https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/windows-build-crashes-when-project-is-imported-from-newer-version

Comment: No, I started the project with unity 5.5. That is the only version i have.

Comment: And always f3. Not f2, no later patch releases or anything like that?

Comment: always f3. I never upgraded. I started a few months ago.

Comment: Okay, unless someone else has other suggestions, nothing obvious stands out regarding user error. So if you can repro it in another project, you might have an issue you could submit to Unity. You can always try to see if it happens in one of the more recent patch releases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134179/discussion-between-mad-mask-and-bart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Issue was Unity related.

I downloaded today Unity 5.5.1f1 and i made a new build.

I launched the ".exe" without crashing.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of opening the unity.exe try opening it from your asset.

Comment: i m not talking about the unity.exe. I m talking about the exe of the game generated after the build. So in unity when i click play all is ok , but if i build the game and try to launch it , it crash.